# Does edianness in the global header (.pcap) apply only to the header or to the whole pcap file?

Tags: endianness, pcap

I'm writing a program in python3 to analyze a .pcap file and I'm just wondering if the endianness (little endian or big endian) applies to all packets, or just the main header.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It applies to:

- the file header;
- the per-packet header (time stamp, captured length, on-the-network length);
- some meta-data headers in the packet contents (`LINKTYPE_NULL`, `LINKTYPE_USB_LINUX`, `LINKTYPE_USB_LINUX_MMAPPED`, `LINKTYPE_IEEE802_11_PRISM`, `LINKTYPE_NFLOG`, `LINKTYPE_PFLOG`);
- some fields in the CANbus header in `LINKTYPE_LINUX_SLL`/`LINKTYPE_LINUX_SLL2` captures).

Other fields in the packet contents are in whatever byte order the protocol containing the field in question specifies - for example, multi-byte integral-valued fields in the IPv4, IPv6, UDP, and TCP headers are big-endian regardless of the endianness of the file and per-packet headers.